# OLEDB Converting "#" to "." while writing excel header column

Tags: excel, oledb

[image]
I have a working code where I create multiple sheets to the workbook and add data to it. Everything works fine except one thing. I want to write column header with **#** suffix. **DOCTOBOX#** is the header I need instead of plain header name. OLEDB provider always converts **#** to **.** while writing to excel. Other special characters are just fine. I tried all possible way to make it work, however, does not seem to work only for **#** which always convert it to **.** and my column name in excel appears **DOCTOBOX.**

```
string filePath = @"C:\FileDownload\";
    string filename = "MultipleExcelSheet_" + 
    DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss") + ".xls";

     string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    "Data Source=C:\\FileDownload\\MultipleExcelSheet_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy_HH_mm_ss") + ".xls;" +
    "Extended Properties=&quot;Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=0&quot;";

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
      {
                    conn.Open();
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
     {
        string sheetname = "LOB_" + j;

        string sheetSql1 = "CREATE TABLE " + sheetname + " (id varchar(50), [DOCTOBOX#] varchar(50), [BirthDate@] varchar(50))";
      using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sheetSql1 , conn))
       {
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
    sheetSql1 = "INSERT INTO " + sheetname + " VALUES ('1', 'ListOfOrders', '02/02/2012')";
      OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sheetSql1, conn);
      cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

        conn.Close();

      Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
      Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
      Response.TransmitFile(filePath + filename);
      Response.End();
    }
```